System.JSONException: Unexpected character (' ' (code 8195 / 0x2003)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at this line of code
@RestResource(urlMapping='/msy/files/*')
global class MSY_LinkCVToFilesService {
    @HttpPost
    global static List<FileWrapper> linkcvtoFiles(){
        String body = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
        system.debug('body----'+body);
        FileWrapper request = (FileWrapper)JSON.deserialize(body,FileWrapper.class);
}
 global class FileWrapper{
        global String id;
        global String fileId;
        global String fileName;
        global String fileType;
        global String applicationId;
        global String uploadedBy; 
    }
}

request :{
   "id": "string",
  "fileId": "string",
  "fileName": "string",
  "fileType": "String",
  "Appid" : "string",
  "uploadedBy": "string"
}

Getting error like this while sending request from postman :

"errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
"message": "
"FileWrapper request =
(FileWrapper)JSON.deserialize(body,FileWrapper.class);"

Please give me some solution for this one.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Since you're using RestContext.request.requestBody.toString(), your payload should not include the "request" part of the payload:
{
   "id": "string",
  "fileId": "string",
  "fileName": "string",
  "fileType": "String",
  "Appid" : "string",
  "uploadedBy": "string"
}

However, if you want to use the request wrapper, use the parameterized version of the method:
@HttpPost
global static List<FileWrapper> linkcvtoFiles(FileWrapper request){

This requires proper JSON, however, so the request would become:
{ 
    "request": {
       "id": "string",
      "fileId": "string",
      "fileName": "string",
      "fileType": "String",
      "Appid" : "string",
      "uploadedBy": "string"
    }
}

Note the outer object notation and quoting field names.
